# Import properties from an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to import a single function from a functions file. The functions file looks like this.

```
const Functions = {
    url(path = '') {
        path = path.replace(/^\/+/, '');
        return `${document.baseURI}/${path}`;
    },

    asset(path = '') {
        return this.url(path);
    }
};

export default Functions;
```

I then try to import the `url` function like this.

```
import {url} from "../Utils/Functions";
```

When I do this, I get the following error in-browser from browserify.

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _Functions.url) is not a function

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import) docs, this import should work as `url` is in the `Functions` object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `import url from "../Utils/Functions";` will work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done - is exported an object.

In that case you need to import an object and access its property:

```
import Functions from "../Utils/Functions";
Functions.url();
```

If you want to make named export - you need to change the way you're exporting and defining it:

```
function url(path = '') {
    path = path.replace(/^\/+/, '');
    return `${document.baseURI}/${path}`;
}

function asset(path = '') {
    return this.url(path);
}

export { url, asset };
```

or

```
export function url(path = '') {
    path = path.replace(/^\/+/, '');
    return `${document.baseURI}/${path}`;
}

export function asset(path = '') {
    return this.url(path);
}
```

As another note: it is not destructuring, even though it looks similar. The standard names it as `ImportsList` and defines its own semantic, different from the destructuring one.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports

Comment: I incorrectly assumed that destructuring could be used on an imported object.

Comment: @Enijar the thing is that - it's not destructuring, even though it looks slightly similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you use 'default export' then the import should be:

```
import Functions from "../Utils/Functions";
```

Actually, you can import it with any identifier you like (not only 'Functions')